# Storing correct answers and keeping track

Tags: python

I am new to Stack overflow and have only recently began learning Python Programming. I am currently using Python 2.7 so there will be differences in my code compared to Python v3.

Anyway, I decided that I wanted to write a program that I can let my nephew and niece try out. The program created is a test with mathematics.

The code may not be the best or compact as it should be but it's my first go at it.

I have attached the code I have typed so far here. Please let me know your thoughts and any feedback.

**My main question though is here:**

- I want to store the correct answers that the user-inputs in a variable. I want to then be able to output the number of questions that the user has got correct at the end of the test.

For example, if the user decides to take on a challenge of 5 problem sets and gets 3 correct, I want the program to output, you got 3/5 correct. I have a feeling that this will be something very simple but I have not yet thought of it.

I have tried to create a variable such as answersCorrect = 0 and then just answersCorrect += 1 to increment each time an answer is correct but I can't seem to make that work so I have left it off.

Any suggestions for this?

```
from sys import exit
```

import random
from random import randint
import math

def addition():
    problems = int(input("How many problems do you want to solve?\n"))

```
random.seed()
count = 0
answersRight = 0

while count < problems:
    num_1 = randint(1,12)
    num_2 = randint(1,12)

    userAnswer = int(input("What is " + str(num_1) + "+" + str(num_2) + "? "))
    generatedAnswer = (num_1 + num_2)

    if userAnswer == generatedAnswer:
        print "Correct"
        answersRight += 1
    else:
        print "Sorry, the answer is ", generatedAnswer, "\n"
    count += 1

    print "running score of answers right ", answersRight, " out of ", problems

print "Would you like to solve more problems?"
repeatAnswer = raw_input("> ")

if repeatAnswer == "Yes" or repeatAnswer == "Y" or repeatAnswer == "YES":
    start()
elif repeatAnswer == "No" or repeatAnswer == "N" or repeatAnswer == "NO":
    print "Thank you for completing the test anyway..."
    exit()
else:
    print "You have not entered a valid response, goodbye!"
    exit()
```

def subtraction():
    problems = int(input("How many problems do you want to solve?\n"))

```
random.seed()
count = 0
answersRight = 0

while count < problems:
    num_1 = randint(1,12)
    num_2 = randint(1,12)

    userAnswer = int(input("What is " + str(num_1) + "-" + str(num_2) + "? "))
    generatedAnswer = (num_1 - num_2)


    if userAnswer == generatedAnswer:
        print "Correct"
        answersRight += 1
    else:
        print "Sorry, the answer is ", generatedAnswer, "\n"
    count += 1


    print "running score of answers right ", answersRight, " out of ", problems

print "Would you like to solve more problems?"
repeatAnswer = raw_input("> ")

if repeatAnswer == "Yes" or repeatAnswer == "Y" or repeatAnswer == "YES":
    start()
elif repeatAnswer == "No" or repeatAnswer == "N" or repeatAnswer == "NO":
    print "Thank you for completing the test anyway..."
    exit()
else:
    print "You have not entered a valid response, goodbye!"
    exit()
```

def multiply():
    problems = int(input("How many problems do you want to solve?\n"))

```
random.seed()
count = 0
answersRight = 0

while count < problems:
    num_1 = randint(1,12)
    num_2 = randint(1,12)

    userAnswer = int(input("What is " + str(num_1) + "x" + str(num_2) + "? "))
    generatedAnswer = (num_1 * num_2)

    if userAnswer == generatedAnswer:
        print "Correct"
        answersRight += 1
    else:
        print "Sorry, the answer is ", generatedAnswer, "\n"
    count += 1


    print "running score of answers right ", answersRight, " out of ", problems

print "Would you like to solve more problems?"
repeatAnswer = raw_input("> ")

if repeatAnswer == "Yes" or repeatAnswer == "Y" or repeatAnswer == "YES":
    start()
elif repeatAnswer == "No" or repeatAnswer == "N" or repeatAnswer == "NO":
    print "Thank you for completing the test anyway..."
    exit()
else:
    print "You have not entered a valid response, goodbye!"
    exit()
```

def divide():
    problems = int(input("How many problems do you want to solve?\n"))

```
random.seed()
count = 0
answersRight = 0

while count < problems:
    num_1 = randint(1,12)
    num_2 = randint(1,12)

    userAnswer = int(input("What is " + str(num_1) + "/" + str(num_2) + "? "))
    generatedAnswer = (num_1 / num_2)

    if userAnswer == generatedAnswer:
        print "Correct"
        answersRight += 1
    else:
        print "Sorry, the answer is ", generatedAnswer, "\n"
    count += 1


    print "running score of answers right ", answersRight, " out of ", problems

print "Would you like to solve more problems?"
repeatAnswer = raw_input("> ")

if repeatAnswer == "Yes" or repeatAnswer == "Y" or repeatAnswer == "YES":
    start()
elif repeatAnswer == "No" or repeatAnswer == "N" or repeatAnswer == "NO":
    print "Thank you for completing the test anyway..."
    exit()
else:
    print "You have not entered a valid response, goodbye!"
    exit()
```

def start():
    # Welcome messages
    print "Welcome to this amazing game called Mathemagica!"
    print "I hope you are ready for an amazing challenge :D"
    print "My name is Mr MATHEMAGIC and i'm here to test you on your abilities"
    print "...."
    print "So, to begin please enter your Name: "
    name = raw_input("> ")
    print "Right. ", name, " Please enter your Age: "
    age = raw_input("> ")
    print "Thanks! So, ", name, " are you ready to begin your Mathematics Test? (Yes / No)"
    response = raw_input("> ")

```
# Response Dependant directing to a particular function to be CALLED
if response == "Yes" or response == "YES" or response == "Y" or response == "y":
    print """Which test would you like to take first? Please select an option below:
        \t1. Addition
        \t2. Subtraction
        \t3. Multiplication
        \t4. Division
        """
    # Resonse here
    problemSolver = raw_input("> ")
    # Evaluating what option has been selected
    if problemSolver == "1":
        addition()
    elif problemSolver == "2":
        subtraction()
    elif problemSolver == "3":
        multiply()
    elif problemSolver == "4":
        divide()
    else:
        print "You have not entered a valid option, Goodbye!"
        exit()
elif response == "No" or response == "NO" or response == "N" or response == "n":
    print "That's fine. Have a good day :)"
    exit(0)
else:
    print"You have not entered a valid response, Bye"
```

start()

Comment: Your idea of using an answersCorrect variable is a good one. What did not work about it? This would be a better question if you left that in and highlighted where it didn't work using that approach.

Comment: Hey I'm not sure how I can add further code onto this comment but this is what I have added as an example for the addition() function..

Comment: answersRight = 0
        if userAnswer == generatedAnswer:
            print "Correct"
            # answersRight Tracker
            answersRight += 1
            print "running score of answers right ", answersRight, " out of ", problems

The above has "running score of answers right  1  out of  5" output each time but does not increment if further answers are correct.. so I'm not sure what is wrong here?

Comment: Hard to say for sure (you should edit your question instead of commenting), but it looks like you wrote answersRight = 0 inside the while loop, which would reset it each time

Comment: Hey, sorry I never realised. I have edited the initial code now so you should be able to see where I have replaced my answersRight = 0 and then the counter += 1 within each function but outside of the while loop. This still doesn't appear to work with an output of: "running score of answers right  1  out of  5" But this does not change to reflect the answers which are correct... Look forward to your response. Many thanks.

Comment: Side note: use `raw_input` everywhere. Don't use `input` in Python 2. It is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`.

Comment: Ahh right. Many thanks Mark :).

Comment: As a completely unrelated note: if you're just learning Python, start doing 3 (unless you have a really good reason not to); partly because support is officially dropped in 2020, and partially because Py3 is better in most ways ( I can't think of a way py2 is better).

Comment: To be honest, I don't have a particularly good reason to use Python 2. I was learning from Learn Python The Hard Way to begin with and that resource used Python 2. Alright, I better get onto Python 3. I suspect I will have to change more than just the print "" on my code here..print("") rather than just print ""..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful about where you place statements with respect to whether they are inside ifs and loops or not. Here is the correct code for addition, the others will be similar:

```
def addition():
    problems = int(input("How many problems do you want to solve?\n"))

    random.seed()
    count = 0
    answersRight = 0

    while count < problems:
        num_1 = randint(1,12)
        num_2 = randint(1,12)

        userAnswer = int(input("What is " + str(num_1) + "+" + str(num_2) + "? "))
        generatedAnswer = (num_1 + num_2)

        if userAnswer == generatedAnswer:
            print "Correct"
            answersRight += 1
        else:
            print "Sorry, the answer is ", generatedAnswer, "\n"
        count += 1

        print "running score of answers right ", answersRight, " out of ", problems

    start()
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much. I will take that into account for any future ones I do. I have added additional functionality as you may see in the edited code above. I would like to build this game into a small application with a user interface. I'm not sure the best way to go about doing this..Whether to use PyQt or Tkinter or anything else. I want the user to be able to have a UI that they can interact with, click buttons and type inside a box.. 

Again I'm very new relative to a lot of members here so I'm not entirely sure. Any suggestions? 

Many thanks.

Comment: If this answer helped you please accept it (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). As for which GUI to use, stackoverflow tries to steer clear of asking for recommendations on what language or framework to use as the answers to those questions are often a matter of opinion, resulting in no clear answer. You might try searching for a different forum on the web to get advice.